# how can I firebase database reference sending other page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase

I want only one announce my firebase database reference object

so I try this....

**index.php**
(javascript)

```
var auth, database, userInfo;
var Attendances_monthlyRef, Attendances_dailyRef, UsersRef;
database = firebase.database();

auth = firebase.auth();
var authProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); //구글 인증창 선언
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if (user) { //인증 성공 → need for login?
    userInfo = user;
    Attendances_dailyRef = database.ref('Attendances_daily/'+userInfo.uid );
    document.GetValue.Database.value = JSON.stringify(Attendances_dailyRef);
    } else { 
      auth.signInWithPopup(authProvider);
    }
})
```

(html)

```
<form action="TimeSheet.php" name="GetValue" method="post">
    <input type=submit style='font-size:16pt' value="シフト画面に行こう"/>
    <input type=textarea name="Database" style='font-size:16pt'/>
</form>
```

**TimeSheet.php**
(php)

```
<?php
  $AuthUser = json_decode($_POST["Database"]); //Ref
  print_r($AuthUser);
?>
```

(javascript)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase.js"> </script>
<script>
function DBmodify() {
  var buttonText = document.getElementById("modify").value;
  if(buttonText == "修正終了") {

    var Ref='<?=$AuthUser?>';
    console.log(Ref);

    Ref.on('value', function(data){
      alert(data.val());
    });
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. because of Ref type.
I send it JSON type, but it sended just text type(http address)

I want to know how can i send firebase database reference in web to other page. 
is there any way?

(of course I know way 
-> other firebase init in other page, but I want to use just one object)

==== edit ====

unfortunately my server native is **php5.6** so I CAN'T USE FIREBASE PHP SDK

Comment: are you try with creating one common file and required this file on another page?

Comment: @Reena Mori No, I can't try that way. How can do that work? :0

Comment: create firebase ref on one file(ref.php) and load this file on another page using include or require function

Comment: @Reena Mori Thank you for your advice! I will Test that! :D